# Unable to connect to the remote server - jQuery is possible, HttpWebRequest .NET fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, tomcat, azure, httpwebrequest

I'm setting up a ASP.NET MVC project in Azure and their will be a connection to my Tomcat webserivce.

In the controller I do a HttpWebRequest to the webservice but when I go to the website in Azure, I get the following message:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

If I do a jQuery request to the server in my MVC View, I get a message from the webservice.

Is the problem the webserivce or maybe CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) problem?

Anybody got a idea/solution?

Comment: What url are you using in the HttpWebRequest? Localhost or the cloudapp.net address?

Comment: I use the url: http://192.168.50.205:8080/restofurlstring, so it is the localhost url. So I guess that's the problem, but why is it reachable by jQuery?

Comment: Probably because jQuery executes on the client (in your browser) and you have access to that IP address from your computer.

Comment: Where is your tomcat web service? On the same machine? If so, use the loopback address (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `HttpWebRequest` executes on the server, while a jQuery requests executes locally on the client. In the comments on your question I can see you are trying to access a local IP address: 192.168.50.205. This explains why the jQuery requests works and the `HttpWebRequest` doesn't: you can access that IP address from your computer, so the local jQuery requests works, but your server can't access that IP address so the `HttpWebRequest` fails.

Comment: While I'm reading I do not understand why I didn't figure it out by myself... It's quite logic. Thanks!